# How to access automatically generated Foreign Key by entity framwork? (Add linked data)

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm making a MVC website with Entity Frameworks. 
I'm using the code first approach so I made my database via code.

I have a database with 3 tables:

tblTtypes `(1-*)` tblRestaurants `(1-*)` tblRecensies

The model of my `tblRestaurants` is like this:

```
[Table("tblTypes")]
  public class Types
  {
    [Key]
    public int PK_TypeNr { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TypeKeuken { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string TypeZaak { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public bool Vegetarisch { get; set; }

    public List<Restaurants> Restaurants { get; set; }
  }
```

The list `List<Restaurants> Restaurants` is a link to the other table (Entity frameworks automatically notices that and adds a FK)

`RestaurantController` looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PK_RestaurantNr,RestaurantNaam,Adres,Website,Aantal_Beoordelingen")] Restaurants restaurants)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Restaurants.Add(restaurants);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(restaurants);
        }
```

The model `Restaurants` looks like:

```
  [Table("tblRestaurants")]
  public class Restaurants
  {
    [Key]
    public int PK_RestaurantNr      { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string RestaurantNaam    { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Adres             { get; set; }
    public string Website           { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Aantal_Beoordelingen { get; set; }

    public List<Recensies> Recensies { get; set; }
  }
```

I added my data like this:

```
Restaurants rest5 = new Restaurants()
      {
        PK_RestaurantNr = 5,
        RestaurantNaam = "Terra",
        Adres = "Frederik Lintstraat 5, Leuven, België",
        Website = "http://www.terra-leuven.be/",
        Aantal_Beoordelingen = 4
      };

      t1.Restaurants = new List<Restaurants>();
      t1.Restaurants.Add(rest5);
```

My views were automatically created.

The problem: when I want to add a new `Restaurant` I also want to link it to a `Type`. But how can I access the automatically generated Foreign Key (generated by entity frameworks)?

Comment: How do you know which type you want the new Restaurant to have?

Comment: @CraigW.I want to add an input field where I can add a Foreign key (The problem is that I don't know where I can do that)

Comment: Can you please post what the code looks like for `Restaurants`?

Comment: @IronMan84 I edited my post with the code of `RestaurantsController` and the model `Restaurants`

Comment: I noticed that your Controller is including in its bind a reference to `Types_PK_TypeNr`. Are you sure it's not in your `Restaurants` class? Is it somewhere else in the application?

Comment: @IronMan84 Indeed, you should ignore that. That was a test that I forgot to delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have that in your `Restaurants` class in order for you to be able to set it. You should put in something like this:

```
[ForeignKey("RestaurantType")]
public int TypesID { get; set; }

public virtual Types RestaurantType { get; set; }
```

After that, all you need to do is to set `TypesID` to the ID of the Type that you want to use, and save it. From then on the `RestaurantType` property will be populated, and you will have linked the `Restaurant` to the `Types` record that you wanted.

One last thing to note is that you **must set `TypesID`and not the navigational property**. If you set the navigational property you will find yourself creating duplicates. I've written a blog post on that [here](http://www.paragon-inc.com/resources/blogs-posts/fixing_duplicate_records_in_entity_framework).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have some questions: 
I edited my beginpost to show you how I add my data.(So I create a restaurant and at the end I add that restaurant to a type) Is that the wrong way? How should I change that in order to work? :/

Comment: If what you have above doesn't work, then add to your `Restaurants` class what I wrote above, and add the `Types` to the record.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean by the comment above. @IronMan84

Comment: So instead of adding my new restaurant to the list of types I should just add a Foreign key?

Comment: Add a foreign key and assign values to it and then save. The relationship should be persisted to the database.

Comment: One is glad to be of service.

Comment: One last question: can u tell me what this piece of your code does exactly: `public virtual Types RestaurantType { get; set; }`

Comment: 1) It will allow you to access the `Types` record that you've attached to this `Restaurant` record. 2) It helps set up the relationship between the tables if you were using code-first.